# Not able to switch focus on main Tab in a browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a simple google login scenario using selenium. But when I run the test case settings tab gets opened automatically and I cannot switch to the tab where the actual execution is going on. I am using the following code:-

```
package Basic;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
public class ChromeDriverTest {     
     public static void main(String[] args) {           
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\chromedriver_new.exe");
     ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
     driver.get("https:/www.google.com/"); 
     } 
}.
```

[image]
Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your Question:

I don't see any error as such in your code but you need to implement some strategies here:

1. As per best practices you must try to keep the chrome driver name as `chromedriver.exe`, though no harm in keeping as `chromedriver_new.exe`
2. Try to bump up your Selenium to v3.4.0, chromedriver to v2.29 & Chrome to 58.x so that you can overcome a lot of basic issues which existed in previous chromedriver & Chrome releases.
3. Your Microsoft Antimalware is trying to reset your browser settings, so I would suggest you to deactivate the Antimalware from your Test Environment so driver can perform without any intervention.
4. To get rid of the info bar you need to take help of `ChromeOptions` class to deactivate the info bar.
5. Use the `WebDriver` interface instead of `ChromeDriver` implementation while you initialize the `driver` instance as follows: `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
6. Finally, your code block will look like:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe"); 
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
   driver.get("https:/www.google.com/");
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I am not able to implement step 3 what you have mentioned here.
Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Did you install any anti-malware extension on Google chrome? If so deactivate/disable/delete that extension manually from Chrome settings.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version of chrome and now it is working fine. Thanks. :)

Comment: @AkashRaj Great Can you accept the Answer please? Thanks

Comment: Yes, Sure. :)@Dev

Comment: To Accept the Answer you need to click on the tick mark beside the Answer. On Accepting the Answer, the tick mark will appear green in color. Thanks

Comment: Yes , Just noticed.